# Visa for Hungary

Tags: uk, schengen, indian-citizens, hungary

I am planning to Hungary, but an issue is that it has just been more than 1 month since I have been in UK. Therefore I have only one UK salary slip (one month UK bank statement) and rest of the salary slips and bank statements are from India.

Please let me know if I will be able to get Schengen visa. I will be travelling Hungary only for 9 days.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody can say for sure whether you can get a visa for Hungary except for the Hungarian authorities.  There's nothing that would automatically disqualify you.  Your relatively recent status in the UK might raise questions, but on the other hand the fact that you are employed in the UK will suggest that you are unlikely to misuse a Schengen visa.